# How do I resolve runtime error 5479 when trying to select multiple documents?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I attempted to write a macro to find a word and bookmark it and to do this for multiple documents, same word and same bookmark across all documents. However, if I select multiple documents, I get an error that says:

> Runtime error 5479
>   You cannot close Microsoft word because a dialogue box is open.

I click OK, switch to Word and then close the dialog box. I'm running it in Word 2013 running on Windows 7.

I would expect it to open each Word doc, find the term "TBC", add the bookmark UMR, and then save and close the document, then it would open the next document and do the same until it ran out of documents.

What actually happens is it changes the first one, and then I get the runtime error. The line that gets highlighted when I hit debug is:

```
documents.Open dlgFile.SelectedItems (nDocx)
```

Here is my VBA:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim myRange As Range
  Set dlgFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  With dlgFile
    dlgFile.AllowMultiSelect = True
    If .Show = -1 Then

      For nDocx = 1 To dlgFile.SelectedItems.Count

        Documents.Open dlgFile.SelectedItems(nDocx)
        MsgBox (ActiveDocument)
        Set objDocx = ActiveDocument

            Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
            With myRange.Find
                Do While .Execute(FindText:="TBC", MatchCase:=True)
                   ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="UMR", Range:=myRange
                   myRange.Select
                   objDocx.Save
                   objDocx.Close
                Loop
               End With
            Set objDocx = Nothing
       Next nDocx

Else
  MsgBox ("You need to select documents first!")
  Exit Sub

End If

  End With

  MsgBox ("You have added all the bookmarks.")


End Sub
```

Comment: Your do While look is doing multiple additions of the same bookmark.  Is this what you want.  Only the last added bookmark will survive.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to save and close the document while still in the middle of a search. It seems that this behaves as if the find dialog box is still open and prevents the document closing properly, which then prevents the next document being loaded. Try moving save and close outside the `While` loop:

```
For nDocx = 1 To dlgFile.SelectedItems.Count

  Documents.Open dlgFile.SelectedItems(nDocx)
  MsgBox (ActiveDocument)
  Set objDocx = ActiveDocument

  Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
  With myRange.Find
    Do While .Execute(FindText:="TBC", MatchCase:=True)
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="UMR", Range:=myRange
      myRange.Select
    Loop
  End With
  objDocx.Save
  objDocx.Close
  Set objDocx = Nothing
Next nDocx
```

(this works in Word 2016, but I do get slightly different behaviour with your original code - all the documents stay open but with no runtime errors. I don't have 2013 here to check.)

Comment: Thank you. it makes perfect sense now. really appreciate your help. can't thank you enough